# How do you make a responsive table that is either a single column or one that scrolls?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hey friends I'm trying to do the media queries for this particular page on this website I'm making. I'm writing it for a max width of 425px and my problem is a table near the bottom of the page. I would like to make it a single column for mobile purposes but from what I read its more popular to make it scroll-able. How can I do this?

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
}

/*---HEADER---*/

header {
 background: red;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
}

.careers-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

header h1 {
 color: white;
 font-size: 5rem;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 margin: 0;
}

/*---NAV---*/

nav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

li a {
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

ul {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55rem;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
}

li a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
 position: relative;
 left: 12px;
 top: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 width: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.25);
}

.logo {
 color: red;
 font-size: 3.7rem;
 margin: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

/*---FORM---*/

form {
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.15);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.form h2 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form h2:after {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.form h2:before {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.form .row {
 margin: 20px;
 display: flex;
}

label {
 color: black;
}

label, input {
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
}

.label {
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.3);
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.middle {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.row-1 input, .row-3 input {
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
}

.row-2 input {
 width: 100%;
}

.row-4 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-4 input, .row-4 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-5  {
 flex-direction: column;
}

.radio {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.row-6 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-6 input, .row-6 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-7 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-7 .col {
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

.row-8 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-8 .col {
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

.crime-textarea {
 margin-top: 10px;
 display: none;
 resize: none;
}

#crime-yes:checked ~ textarea {
 display: block;
}

.row-9 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-9 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-9 input {
 margin-left: 15px;
 flex-grow: 1;
}

.row-10 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-10 input, .row-10 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-11 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-11 input, .row-11 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-12 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-12 input, .row-12 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-13  {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-13 input, .row-13 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

h3 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 text-align: center;
}

/*---TABLE---*/

table {
 width: 95%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 border-spacing: 15px;
}

thead tr {
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.3);
 color: black;
}

thead th {
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani'; 
}

th td {
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

tbody input {
 width: 100%;
}

#submit {
 background-color: red;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 padding: 7px;
 width: 35%;
 align-self: center;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 display: block;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#submit:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #cc0000;
}

/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer .wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

.footer div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.footer .inner {
 margin-left: 55px;
}

.social .inner {
 margin-left: 45px;
}

.contact .inner {
 margin-left: 35px;
}

.footer .inner:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 27.1%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 54px;
}


.links .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 10.5%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -151px;
}

.social .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 5.8%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -171px;
}

.contact .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 7.5%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -174.5px;
}

.wrap:before {
 content: '';
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
}

.links a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.contact p {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}

.social i {
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 margin-right: 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.social i:hover {
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#msg {
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.footer-textarea {
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.2);
 outline: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 resize: none;
 width: 102%;
}

.footer button {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 23.2%;
 margin-top: -40px;
 border: none;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 transition: all ease 0.4s;
 outline: none;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: red;
}

.dark {
 color: red;
}

.copyright {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}



/*-------MEDIA QUERIES-------*/




@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  display: none;
 }

 .ham-menu {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .m1, .m2, .m3 {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

 form {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
 }

 .row {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .middle {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .row-1 input, .row-3 input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
 }

 .row-4 input, .row-6 input {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
 }

 .row-9 input {
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 #submit {
  width: 90%;
 }
 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 33%;
  margin-top: -152px;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 18%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -44px;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 24%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -148px;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 #msg {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25.5%;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
 }

 .footer button {
  right: 9.25%;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 7px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Careers | Kane Concrete & Construction LLC</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/careers.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="careers-wrapper">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <div class="ham-menu">
      <div class="m1"></div>
      <div class="m2"></div>
      <div class="m3"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li class="after"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>

   <h1>Join Our Team</h1>
  </div> 
 </header>

 <section class="form">
 <h2>We're Hiring</h2>

  <form action="" method="" id="form">
   <h3>General Information</h3>
   <div class="row row-1">
    <input type="text" name="First" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="Last" placeholder="Last Name" class="middle">
    <input type="text" name="SSN" placeholder="SSN">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-2">
    <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address">
   </div>
   
   <div class="row row-3">
    <input type="text" name="City" placeholder="City">
    <input type="text" name="State" placeholder="State" class="middle">
    <input type="text" name="Zipcode" placeholder="Zipcode">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-4">
    <div class="label"><label for="Primary-Phone" class="row-4">Primary-Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="Primary-Phone" placeholder="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx">
    <div class="label"><label for="Cell-Phone" class="row-4">Cell-Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="Cell-Phone" placeholder="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-5">
    <label>Are you 18 years old or older?</label>
    <div class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="ageYears" value="Yes" id="ageYearsYes">
     <label for="ageYearsYes">Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" name="ageYears" value="No" required="" id="ageYearsNo">
     <label for="ageYearsNo">No</label>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row row-6">
    <div class="label"><label>Desired Wage:</label></div>
    <input type="text" id="wage-desired">
    <div class="label"><label>Available Start Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" id="start-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-7">
    <div class="col">
     <label>Are you legally authorized to work in the U.S?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="legally" value="Yes" id="legally-yes">
      <label for="legally-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="legally" value="No" required="" id="legally-no">
      <label for="legally-no">No</label>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
     <label>Are you willing to submit to a drug test?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="drug-test" value="Yes" id="drug-yes">
      <label for="drug-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="drug-test" value="No" required="" id="drug-no">
      <label for="drug-no">No</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row row-8">
    <div class="col">
     <label>Have you ever been convicted of a crime? If yes, please explain.</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="crime-answer" value="Yes" id="crime-yes">
      <label for="crime-yes" id="crime-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="crime-answer" value="No" required="" id="crime-no">
      <label for="crime-no">No</label>
      <textarea name="crime-info" cols="70" rows="4" class="crime-textarea"></textarea>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
     <label class="">How did you hear about this job?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="friend" id="friend">
      <label for="friend">friend</label>
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="online" id="online">
      <label for="friend">online</label>
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="other" id="other">
      <label for="other">other</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <hr>
   <h3>Employment History</h3>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>
   
   <table>
    <h3>Refrences</h3>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>RELATIONSHIP</th>
      <th>COMPANY</th>
      <th>PHONE NUMBER</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </form>
 </section>

 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="links">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1>Quick Links</h1>

     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="#">Services</a>
     <a href="#">Job Openings</a>
     <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="social">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1>Social</h1>

     <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

     <p id="msg">Send some feedback!</p>
     <button name="msg">Send</button>
     <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="type here..."></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="contact">
    <div class="inner" class="wrap">
     <h1>Contact</h1>

     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Matt</span></p>
     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Keegan</span></p>
     <p><span class="dark">Address</span> - P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
     <p><span class="dark">Email</span> - KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="copyright"><span>&copy; 2019 - Kane Concrete & Construction | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span></div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
`overflow-y: scroll;`
```

on required section